# Not enough space in /var/cache/apt/archives/

Tags: apt, disk-space-utilization, package-management

- Debian 10 desktop with persistence

```
root@debian:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           767M   19M  749M   3% /run
/dev/sdb1       2.9G  2.9G     0 100% /run/live/persistence/sdb1
/dev/loop0      2.6G  2.6G     0 100% /run/live/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /run/live/overlay
/dev/sdb3       4.9G  4.6G   32M 100% /run/live/persistence/sdb3
overlay         4.9G  4.6G   32M 100% /
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.8G   56K  3.8G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           767M  6.8M  761M   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           767M  8.0K  767M   1% /run/user/0
/dev/sda2       239G  229G   10G  96% /media/root/741229F01229B7CE
/dev/sdb4       2.0G   61M  2.0G   3% /media/root/cache-apt
```

- `apt-get update` executes without a single error
- Something happened to firefox-esr on this system.
- `sudo apt install -y python3-venv`

  ```
  Depends: python3-distutils (>= 3.7.2-1~) but it is not going to be installed
  ```

> 1. debian requires firefox-esr or chromium to be installed.  This causing problems with venv install.
> 2. Fix broken firefox-esr:

```
 :~# apt --fix-broken install
```

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
firefox-esr
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
66 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 56.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 19.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
```

- Try apt cleaning options

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove 
sudo apt-get clean
```

- Try re-route the location where .debs are stored:

> Link: [re-route the location where .debs are stored](https://askubuntu.com/a/178911)

```
mkdir /media/apt-mount/
mount /dev/sdb4 /media/root/cache-apt/
sudo mv -i /var/cache/apt /media/apt-mount/
ln -s /media/apt-mount/apt/ /var/cache/apt
```

apt-get update still executes without any error msg

apt --fix-broken install still causes

`E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.`

How to fix not enough free space error ?

Comment: Your partition is full. Time to clean house.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to purge removed packages with lingering data with `dpkg` like

`sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | awk '$1=="rc"{print $2}' | xargs)`

This also cleans out old kernels properly.

Explanation for the `awk` command is that it find lines where the first column is *rc* and prints the second column.

Comment: produced error=> dpkg: error: --purge needs at least one package name argument.....i am suspecting an issue how debian peristence handles dpkg...tmpfs or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can always manually clean out the contents of /var/cache/apt/archives. It's just old downloaded package files. If you don't mind having to download them again if you reinstall, you can remove them all:

```
find /var/cache/apt/archives -name \*.deb -delete
```

To keep the directory from filling up again, you can disable storing downloaded package files by setting

```
Dir::Cache::pkgcache ''
```

in apt.conf. See `man apt.conf`. Or, create a nightly cron job to clean out the directory as above.

Comment: @debian:~# ls /var/cache/apt/archives/ =>
lock  lock.bak partial

Comment: Answer updated.